# Side by side view overlap

Tags: bug, review-page

[image: Screenshot]

Images overlap in reopen review queue. That's all.

Comment: Can you please supply a link to that review?

Comment: @Haney Please find this>> http://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/41412
This is what Molot mentioned in his post. :)

Comment: @Haney http://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/41412 here you go. It seems it's the same Krishna Mohan found already.